# Brute force decryption for a Caesar Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

This is my code on decryption with brute force with the classic Caesar Cipher. The decryption with brute force shows weird results, as when I set a key of 3, it posts the same decrypted string multiple times. In other keys, such as 7, it does not even show the correct decrypted string.

My method on decrypting with brute force is to change every letter in the encrypted message according to the alphabet, therefore there is a for loop of 26 times, as well as another for loop of the message length. It uses the StringBuilder setCharAt method to change the characters in the string.

This is my code only on the decryption using brute force:

```
    void decryptbruteforce(String encryptmessage) {
    
    //Get the standard alphabet
    String standalpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    
    //Convert this message to uppercase
    String encryptmessageupper = encryptmessage.toUpperCase();
    
    StringBuilder sbdecrypt = new StringBuilder(encryptmessageupper);
    
    
    int key;
    int i;
    int index;
    char currentchar;
    char newchar;
    
    //Loop through the 26 keys in the alphabet.
    for (key = 1; key < 27; key++) {
        
        //Loop through the encrypted message
        for (i = 0; i < sbdecrypt.length(); i++) {
            
            //Get the encrypted character
            currentchar = sbdecrypt.charAt(i);
            
            //Get the index in the alphabet
            index = standalpha.indexOf(currentchar);
            
            //If the currentchar is in the alphabet
            if (index != -1) {
                
                //Reduce the character by the key in the alphabet
                index = index - key;
                
                //If the character goes below 0, aka 'A', go back to the end of the alphabet
                if (index < 0) {
                    index = index + 26;
                    
                    //Get the new character in the alphabet
                    newchar = standalpha.charAt(index);
                    
                    //Set the character in the stringbuilder
                    sbdecrypt.setCharAt(i, newchar);
                }
                
                else {
                    
                    //Get the new character in the alphabet
                    newchar = standalpha.charAt(index);
                    
                    //Set the character in the stringbuilder
                    sbdecrypt.setCharAt(i, newchar);
                }
            }
        }
        
        //Print the key and the resulting string
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Decrypted String: " + sbdecrypt);
    }
}
```

This is my output:
[Caesar Cipher key of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32VPc.png)
[Caesar Cipher key of 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upmEU.png)

This is the link to my whole code if it helps: https://gist.github.com/cliven-hew/35e9458c24d5f5b1ace97b7146ec429a

Comment: It's helpful to put the console results in text, similar to your code instead of a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are always editing the same `StringBuilder sbdecrypt` object. So when you did your shift with a key 1, your next attempt was not based on shifting the original string, it was the previously shifted string. This is why you go from `N....` to `L....` while skipping `M....` and this pattern continues throughout.

You can fix this by adding `sbdecrypt = new StringBuilder(encryptmessageupper);` after your `for (key = 1; key < 27; key++)` line.

```
  public static void decryptbruteforce(String encryptmessage) {

    String standalpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String encryptmessageupper = encryptmessage.toUpperCase();
    StringBuilder sbdecrypt = new StringBuilder(encryptmessageupper);
    
    int key;
    int i;
    int index;
    char currentchar;
    char newchar;

    for (key = 1; key < 27; key++) {
      //Ensure you do your shift on the same string each time.
      //This makes a new object each time
      sbdecrypt = new StringBuilder(encryptmessageupper);

      for (i = 0; i < sbdecrypt.length(); i++) {
        currentchar = sbdecrypt.charAt(i);
        index = standalpha.indexOf(currentchar);
        if (index != -1) {
          index = index - key;
          if (index < 0) {
            index = index + 26;
          }
          newchar = standalpha.charAt(index);
          sbdecrypt.setCharAt(i, newchar);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Decrypted String: " + sbdecrypt);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for solving this problem! The code is working perfectly fine now.